# OpenType properties in OOXML

Tags: openxml, opentype

Is there a way to request specific OpenType properties in OOXML (Office Open XML) ?
For example I would like some digits to be in lining format and some digits to be in old style format. How can this be instructed in the OOXML code?

Here is an example of oldstyle and lining figures (the font is Garamond Premier Pro):
[image]
(It is the same font, only on the upper line the OpenType feature of oldstyle figures is activated.)

Comment: Not really sure how to even try to answer this. What is "lining format"? What is "old style" format?

Comment: @ToddMain they're typography terms. Lining figures are numbers that all sit uniformly between the baseline and x-height, old style numbers don't, and different numbers will descend below the baseline, or ascend beyond the x-height. The image in the post even shows that off quite well.

Comment: @yannis surely the easiest way to find out is to make a document, typeset a word with the opentype features you want, and then saving it and looking at the XML that open office saved? (ODT files are essentially just zip files, so rename it to .zip and unpack it)

Comment: Yeah, I just did what Mike suggested. It's pretty straight-forward. One run will be `<w:r>.<w:rPr>.<w14:numForm w14:val="oldStyle"/>` and the other will be `<w:r>.<w:rPr>.<w14:numForm w14:val="lining"/>`

Comment: Thanks! In fact on my MacOS Word 2016 I didn't found yet how to activate oldstyle/lining figures.